# syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '(' (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I run `rspec spec/models/vote_spec.rb`

I am getting the following error:

```
/Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': /Users/louismorin/code/CP299/app/models/vote.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '(' (SyntaxError)
...:value, inclusion: { in: [-1. 1], message: "%{value is not a...
...                               ^
/Users/louismorin/code/CP299/app/models/vote.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/louismorin/code/CP299/spec/models/vote_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

This is my vote.rb file:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post

  validates :value, inclusion: { in: [-1, 1], message: "%{value} is not a valid vote." }

end
```

Comment: I don't know why the period is showing up in my error because my code is 
```
validates :value, inclusion: { in: [-1, 1], message: "%{value} is not a valid vote." }
```

Comment: That's interesting. Not sure what else to suggest. Perhaps see if you've got multiple vote.rb files. Another thing might be to search all files for `-1. 1`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `in:` option `in: [-1. 1]` should be `in: [-1, 1]` (comma, not period).

Although it looks right in the given `vote.rb` file, the error output shows a period instead of a comma.